# How can you check if your document is opened in an IFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dhtml

Is there a way to know if your page is opened inside of an `IFrame`?

An idea I had was to see if the `window` object has a `.parent` property, but this apparently is also true of standalone windows which are opened by Javascript's `window.open()` function.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if (window.top != window.self)
 {
}
```