# Flex: How to examine if document is loaded in iFrame?

Tags: apache-flex, iframe

I'm using an iFrame to show documents in an flex app using ExternalInterface.

Is there any way (events?) to examine when document loading finished?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Please show us your code and tell us what the expected behaviour is, the actual results, and any errors sso we can help you improve your code or fix any errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you check if your document is opened in an IFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918815/how-can-you-check-if-your-document-is-opened-in-an-iframe)